# Random port opened by ActiveMQ on 0.0.0.0

Tags: activemq-classic

In addition to the "8161" and "61616" ports ActiveMQ opens another random TCP port listening in "0.0.0.0", e.g.: 46479 ([see also](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ports-used-activemq-hpc)).

I am able to change the ports "8161" and "61616" from "0.0.0.0" to "127.0.0.1", but I couldn't find anywhere how to make this change to the third random port.

Listening in "127.0.0.1" instead of "0.0.0.0" is a security requirement in my company (to avoid access from outside the server).

How could I change the random port to listen in "127.0.0.1" instead of "0.0.0.0"?

Answer (score 0):

The random ports in that document refer to the second port in the client-server port-pair when clients connect. This is standard TCP and is not a "listening" port.

To listen only to localhost, simply update your transport connector to specify the IP you wish to listen on vs 0.0.0.0 for all IPs.

`<transportConnector uri="tcp://127.0.0.1:61616" ... />`

Comment: Thanks Matt, but I already set the transportConnector  listening on 127.0.0.1 but the ramdom port is still listening on "0.0.0.0": tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:46479           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31617/java